# Making a Opencart 1.5.6 template responsive with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, opencart

Looking to make my site that runs Opencart 1.5.6 work with mobile and templates.

I have a heavily modified template, but it is not responsive.

Can anyone advise in how to add the Bootstrap functionality to this template?

(Bootstrap is implemented in v2, but I need to stick with this version for a matter of reasons)

Comment: add bootstrap, rewrite HTML according your needs..

Comment: Purchase any responsive theme from the store.

Comment: Check this [click here](http://themeforest.net/item/marketshop-multipurpose-opencart-theme/6913803?ref=harnishdesign)

Answer (score 0):

there are a few templates that are using bootstrap out there. adding bootstrap to your current modified template wouldn't be easier than modifying any new template that you get. i would personally install a separate module for the mobile site if you do not wish to touch your main desktop version. you may do this on a sub-domain etc. and redirect any mobile to this sub-domain